# Where do I get some locals' help or advice about traveling to their country?

Tags: transit, planning, local-customs, local-knowledge

I love traveling and I travel a lot either solo or with friends. But in some countries I face specific problems connected with different languages, peculiar traditions and lifestyle, or simply with lack of knowledge about the city, its transport system, best locations, authentic places.

Is there any source where I can get some help and advice from local people? It would make traveling much easier!

Comment: This will have a different answer depending on the country.

Comment: Kinda looks to me like promoting their site... http://www.meetngreetme.com/users?location=Tel%20Aviv-Jaffa,%20Israel Found noone in that city and there is a "Katya" (Kate?) and a Julia (Juliya?) as workers promoted...both registred today.

Comment: I think @TopQuestions has sussed it; they're working in conjunction here and on Expats.

Answer (score 4):

You can maybe try it with couchsurfing or AirBnB. Don't know about Airbnb by myself but have made pretty good experiences with [couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/).

There is a new Beta-"Hangout". Or simply write to local people to maybe hang out or show you around.

Answer (score 3):

The site you're on, [travel.stackexchange.com](http://travel.stackexchange.com), is used by people from many different countries, and they often answer questions that happen to be about their own country.

Comment: Yes! So much this!